# laravel eloquent - Use without on nested eager loaded relations

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading, eloquent-relationship

I'm currently working on laravel framework and I'm stuck with some relations and eager loading issues.

### Situation

I have three models A, B and C

I have two relations

- A has many B
- B has many C

By default (using the $with attribute in Model) :

- A doesn't include B
- B include C

So most of the time I'm using A without B and B with C

And here is how I've set up the relationship methods & eager loading

```php
class A extends Model {
...

  protected $with = [];

  public function bs() {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Models\B');
  }

}

class B extends Model {
...

  protected $with = ['cs'];

  public function cs() {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Models\C');
  }

  public function a() {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\A');
  }
}

class C extends Model {
...

  public function b() {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\B');
  }
}
```

### Problem

For a specific task I'd like to query A with all B and without any C

When I'am using `A::query()->with('b')` C are loaded by default

So I'am trying to use `A::query()->with('b')->without('b.c')`
But it keep loading B to C relations.

Have you any idea on how to achieve this ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Can you show exactly what your model internals look like - specifically how you've set up the relationship methods?

Comment: I updated my post

Comment: if you are using protected $with = ['cs'] and don't want to load b, then just add without as below

public function cs() {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Models\C')->without('b');
  }

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `Eloquent\Model` has a [`newQueryWithoutRelationships`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L977).

I think you could do the following:

```
(new A())->newQueryWithoutRelationships()->with(...)
```

**Update after [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60195576/laravel-eloquent-use-without-on-nested-eager-loaded-relations/60195716?noredirect=1#comment106503870_60195716)**

Interesting method `without()` (did not know about it).

It looks like you could try the following:

```
A::query()->with(['bs' => function($query) {
    $query->without('c');
}]);
```

Comment: No it doesn't work... `newQueryWithoutRelationships()` remove the relations for model A but not for those I add with the `with()`statement..

Comment: The updated part of the answer doesn't work for me. using `$query->without('c');` still returns c

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because withing `B` class you've used:

```
protected $with = ['cs'];
```

Which will eager load `cs()` relationship with each query.

Once you've removed it, you should see that

```
A::query()->with('b')
```

will only load associated `B` models, without its corresponding `C`'s.

Comment: Yep I know that ! My question is, is there a way to keep my eager loads (because it's the common case for my app) but remove it just for one request ?